# How to identify the port of minimongo running inside meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am novice in meteor. I was developing an application which leverages the mongo db which comes with the meteor package. The meteor is running under the port 3000, but i want to know under what port the mini mongo runs. I am using a tool MongoVUE to view all the collections that is under mongo running in a port. I was able to view the mongo collections when i run the standalone mongo since i know the port for that but for this mini mongo running under meteor i am not able to know the port. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mingomongo runs in the browser, it's a client-side Javascript library.. it runs in memory, it doesn't have a port.. it enables you to query data published by the server in your client application, using MongoAPI style syntax..

to get the connection string of the Mongo instance running on the server (say, if you want to connect from a different client, or just see the port number) run

```
meteor mongo -U
```

Comment: the data is persisted on the server in Mongo, i put the command to view the port number in the answer above..

Comment: I started my app as below.                              S:\Enterest>meteor
[[[[[ S:\Enterest ]]]]]
Running on: http://localhost:3000/
In another command line in the same application directory i tried running your command, it gave me the response as below       S:\Enterest>meteor mongo
mongo: Meteor isn't running.
This command only works while Meteor is running your application
locally. Start your application first.                             Am I missing something here, because if i dont start my application it clearly says please start the application.

Comment: just to give a hint about my previous comment that i am doing this in window. in unix it perfectly gives me the port. thanks for the info. if you can give me some hint on windows it would be great. i will accept your answer.

Comment: ah, i don't have a Windows system to hand - i'm afraid i can't help you.. (Although i don't see any reason it should work any differently)

Comment: either ask another question relating specifically to Windows, ask in the IRC channel or raise a bug on GitHub..

Answer (score 6):

Using `ps auxww|grep mongo|grep meteor` on my Fedora system I get:

```
jwulf    20635  0.3  2.6 150800 41336 pts/1    Sl+  17:07   0:01 /usr/lib/meteor/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --smallfiles --port 3002 --dbpath /home/jwulf/tools/leaderboard/.meteor/local/db
```

So it is running on port 3002 on my system. Starting `mongo` with `--port 3002` allows me to connect to the Meteor mongo server and copy data into the database.

You can also connect to the local instance by running `meteor mongo` in your Meteor app directory.

The database itself is at `<app-name>/.meteor/local/db` on my Fedora system.

Answer (score 1):

In meteor 0.8.3 it's using port 3001

so I run:

mongo localhost:3001
use use meteor

and I'm good to go...thanks to Sitapati Das for the command above...